# EventLog.Entries throws Index out of range Exception

Tags: c#

On the following line

```
EventLogEntry[] entries = _eventLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToArray();
```

Same goes for

```
_eventLog.Entries.CopyTo(..)
```

we sometimes get an IndexOutOfRangeException

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.IntFrom(Byte[] buf, Int32 offset)
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.GetCachedEntryPos(Int32 entryIndex)
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.GetEntryWithOldest(Int32 index)
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.GetEntryAtNoThrow(Int32 index) 
System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryCollection.EntriesEnumerator.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(TSource)(IEnumerable`1 source)
```

We use this to create some kind of Logviewer which is not bound to the machine it runs on.
The object is only accessed from a single trhead.

My guess here is that there sometimes is a "racingcondition".
When you take a look at the [SourceCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/EventLogInternal.cs#1031) it becomes clear that deleting entries while accessing the enumerator is probably the cause of the exception.

Comment: Is it possible that the number of entries is too big?

Comment: Are you reading and writing to the `EventLog` simultaneously?

Comment: @T_D Define 'too big'. Is there a certain value?

Comment: 2,1 billions ^^ see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you mean to the instance of the eventlog or the real evetnlog? Its just a viewer.